# Could not apply withXml() to generated POM > Could not get unknown property 'implementation'

Tags: android, gradle, bintray

I am trying to publish an Android library to bintray. I have set it up in both bintray and my Android project.

`publish.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

version '1.0'
group 'np.com.ngimasherpa'

publishing {
    publications {
        Production(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/emptyviewsupportrecyclerview-release.aar") 
            groupId this.group
            artifactId 'emptyviewsupportrecyclerview'
            version this.version

            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    
                    if (it.name != 'unspecified') {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = project.hasProperty('user') ?: System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = project.hasProperty('apiKey') ?: System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    publications = ['Production']
    configurations = ['archives']
    dryRun = false
    override = false
    publish = true
    pkg {
        repo = 'EmptySupportRecyclerView' 
        name = 'np.com.ngimasherpa.emptyviewsupportrecyclerview' 
        version {
            name = this.version
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = this.version
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to upload the library using `./gradlew bintrayUpload`, I get:

```
    Execution failed for task ':generatePomFileForProductionPublication'.
- Could not apply withXml() to generated POM
- Could not get unknown property 'implementation' for configuration container of type
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.
```

Comment: in my case some changes in artifact("<changes>") solved the issue.